# How to extract data dynamically in python

Tags: python, curl

I am using a python program to replace the general curl command that would automatically hit an api and ask the user to dynamically input data. The general curl command that i want to convert is :
**curl -XPOST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"I am looking for Chinese food"}'**
I have done something like :

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000//parse'
data = '{"q":"abc"}'
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

As long as the query example is static, the result is as expected. But I want the data to dynamic. I'm doing something like :

```
 **data = '{"q":i}'**,
```

where i is the Key part of a dictionary. But this does not work. Suggest the correct format.

Comment: What do you mean you want it to be dynamic?

Comment: I believe you can just pass a Python dictionary as `data`, rather than building a json object as a string.

Comment: `data = {"q": mydict[i]}`

Comment: @SuperStew I want to take the inputs from console once i run the program

Comment: @JohnGordon Tried that too. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @PadmashaChoubey Saying "it doesn't work" tells us nothing.  Please be specific.  Do you get an error?  Does `data[q]` not contain the right information?  Something else?

Comment: @JohnGordon Pardon me for that Sir. To answer your question, the response field takes in the data in a json format. So suppose mydict[i] has "abc" text. So when I print the data it should print- **{"q":"abc"}** Instead it comes out as - {"q": mydict[i]} in your case.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried resolving that using : **str ="\""+inputs[i]+"\""** and then passing in str in data. But this also returns {"q":str}

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mentioned wanting to get the input from the user (aka "dynamic" like you called it) use this:

```
# This will prompt the user to write something in the console and save it as user_input variable
user_input = input('query >> ') 
data = {'q': user_input}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Not of any help due to the reason i mentioned in my comment.